# What is the maximum number of days for which we can keep versions in a Delta table?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake

What is the maximum number of days for which we can keep versions in a Delta table ?

I know by default Delta table keeps 7 days of versions. However, My team wants to keep all the history versions of a delta table (something like versions till last 999years).

I understand there would be Storage cost and performance considerations, but we are ready bear the required costs. It's a small sized delta table (with 1 million records in current version).

I tried to find this info in databricks documentation, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

I just want to know if it is possible to have 999years of version history in a Delta table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the retention period for Delta table versions using the `delta.logRetentionDuration` configuration property.

As per the [Retrieve Delta table history Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/history#retrieve-delta-table-history), history retention is 30 days by default.

You can use the history command to retrieve information about each write operation to a Delta table, including details such as the operations performed, the user who made the changes, and the timestamp of each operation.

As you mentioned, you want the versions to last **999** years.

I have tried the following approach to set the retention period by adjusting the `delta.logRetentionDuration` property to a value in days:

```
%sql
set delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration = "365000"
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: So It seems practically it's possible to store versions till last 1000years, right ?